# how to make wire bend easier to wrap inductors?

Tags: inductor, wire

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyuQB.jpg)

[image]

[image]

so obviously, the wire is thick (for a wire) how to make it easier to wrap around a core?

Comment: You could use multiple strands of thinner wire alongside each other and wire them in parallel (or series if you wish)

Comment: Some improvement: on each part turn pull wire out straight then push section where it comes off the core so it bends at 90 degrees against the core. Then pull wire through. Core acts as bending edge. Be careful not to damage  insulation.

Comment: Using multiple strands in parallel improves the high frequency characteristics because of the skin effect and so may be preferable, depending on the application.

Answer (score 0):

Use a split core and just remove that plastic bobbin then feed the already coiled wire onto the core.

Close the core and even the wire out. May not be as tight...

Comment: Toroids have their place when high permeance is mandatory, so split cores might not be possible. At least more windings will be needed.

Comment: @tobalt more windings on that bobbin than shown on the toroid...

Comment: Pardon, I cant follow